# Update document set item programmatically

Tags: document-set

In the code below I am getting the following Exception :

```
 Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Audit/0003 has been modified by contoso\sp_install.
```

Does the file need to be checked out first? Anyone has got any idea how to solve this?
I can't seem to find example on how to add an item to a document set.

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Audit");
DocumentSet docSet = CreateDocumentSet(list, au.Guid);
SPListItem docSetItem = docSet.Item;

if (list != null)
{
    docSetItem["A1_1_Question"] = au.A1_1_Question;
    docSetItem["A1_2_Question"] = au.A1_2_Question;
    docSetItem.Update();
}

public static DocumentSet CreateDocumentSet(SPList list, string DocumentSetName)
{
    SPContentType docsetCT = list.ContentTypes["Audit"];

    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add("DocumentSetDescription", "New Document Set");
    SPFolder parentFolder = list.RootFolder;
    DocumentSet docSet = DocumentSet.Create(parentFolder, DocumentSetName, docsetCT.Id, properties, true);
    return docSet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the internal name or static name of the fields you are updating. This might cause issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronalg/archive/2011/08/11/documentsets-documentset-create-and-the-properties-hashtable.aspx

If Checkout is required in the document then you have to Checkout the item before updating and Checkin after updating.

```
item.CheckOut();
item.Update();
item.CheckIn();
```

Also check following:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7751d24f-e025-4526-882e-f5f273362f8d/document-set-created-programmatically-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: I tried to use the checkout method, but there is no such method in the documentSet.

Comment: use docSetItem.Checkout() not on document set.

Comment: yes, I used it in the docSetItem.CheckOut() but this method does not exist

Comment: Ok Try docSetItem.SystemUpdate(false) or add some Thread.Sleep beforedocStItem.Update()

Comment: I still get the exception of being modified by me.

Comment: Try web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; before updating.

Comment: Also try docSet.Item.UpdateOverVersion

Comment: I used docSet.Item.UpdateOverVesion but I am still getting the exception: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file AuditSIPP/0012 has been modified by contoso\sp_install

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7751d24f-e025-4526-882e-f5f273362f8d/document-set-created-programmatically-doesnt-work-properly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7751d24f-e025-4526-882e-f5f273362f8d/document-set-created-programmatically-doesnt-work-properly) I was able to solve my issue. this is the code that I used:

```
DocumentSet newDc = DocumentSet.Create(folder, "Docset", docsetCT.Id, properties, true);

DocumentSet MyDocSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(list.GetItemById(newDc.Item.ID).Folder);

MyDocSet.Item["MyField"] = "Test";
MyDocSet.Item.Update();
```